# Trigonometry Problem Involving Finding a Bearing

Tags: trigonometry, word-problem

Problem:

From the Pedimaxus International Airport a tour helicopter can fly to Cliffs of Insanity Point by following a bearing of N8.9°E for 192 miles and it can fly to Bigfoot Falls by following a bearing of S63.4°E for 207 miles. Cliffs of Insanity Point and Bigfoot Falls both lie on a straight stretch of the Great Sasquatch Canyon. What bearing would the tour helicopter need to follow to go directly from Bigfoot Falls to Cliffs of Insanity Point?

Comment: What does N8.9°E and S63.4°E mean? Could you convert them to regular degrees, i.e. between $0$ and $360$ degrees?

Comment: N8.9E and S63.4E are abbreviations for North 8.9° East and South 63.4°. So, the letters simply tell you in what quadrant the angle is in. In regular degrees (clockwise) N8.9°E is 278.9° and S63.4°E is 26.6°.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few days I have come up with the answer.

With the given measurements, we can create a triangle. After this, if we construct two right triangles under and above the main triangle, we can find a way to solve x° like this: [Setup 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rzfp.png). We can get 26.6° since we already know the other two angles of the right triangle. From this we need to find two values in order to find the bearing, shown in this image: [Setup 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3YPZ.png). Side *c* can be found with the law of cosines, and comes to be approximately 322.304. Now, the law of sines can be used to find the angle measure of angle *C* with this equation: $$ \frac{sin(107.7°)}{322.304}= \frac{sin(C°)}{192}$$
This comes to approximately 34.6°. After looking at the image of Setup 3, we see that we know two out of three angles, and since we know these three angles must equal 90°, we can subtract the sum of the two known angles to get 28.8° as the angle measurement for x°. However, since we need to get the bearing, we must put this in bearing form, and since the angle is in quadrant 2, the final answer is N28.8°W.